# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (49041,4) into shape (49041)

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, array-broadcasting

This is my code. 
I'm getting broad cast error.I'm unable to understand why?I have looked at other similar questions, which spoke about problems with dimensions, but I was unable to find out the problem.Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.
I have attached the image.
[Broadcast error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4sDE.png)

Both arrays ( ns and X_train_grade_encoded) are of the same shape , but there is error why?

Comment: The error says that one array is 2d with shape (49041, 4), the other is 1d (49041,).  If you reshaped the 2nd so it was (49041, 1), the `broadcasting` rules would take care of matching the 1 and 4 dimensions.  You may need to read more about `numpy` arrays shapes, and about `broadcasting`.  Don't just search the internet for similar errors; read basic `numpy` docs.

Comment: @hpaulj  Thanks for reply. But,the shape of the second one is (49041, 300). I printed the shape of the second array in the first cell.

Comment: I didn't look at the image link, and don't intend to.

Comment: A 300 wouldn't work with a 4 either.

Comment: But its working at the last cell.
Just to try something else, I flattened the the first array of shape ( 49041,4) and reshaped it to the same, tried to hstack with the  array of shape (49041,300) . That gave the error.
But with the older one of same shapes. it didnt give me an error.

Comment: The wording of the error suggests you are trying to put (n,4) shape into (n,) shape slot or array.

Comment: I understood that,unless there is a common shape or 1, it wont broadcast.

Just to try something else, I flattened the the first array of shape ( 49041,4) and reshaped it to the same, tried to hstack with the array of shape (49041,300) . That gave the error. But if i try hstack with the older ones of same shapes. it didnt give me an error.

Comment: @hpaulji Anyway, Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Why are you using `sparse.hstack`?  The true context of your problem is hidden in that barely readable image!

Comment: @hpaulj  You are correct, The question I put wasn't clear, I should have mentioned that it was scipy.sparse. Sorry for the confusion. I'm going to edit the question now.

I'm using  sparse, because I was training a xgboost model after doing response coding and I had some limitations, The result of encoding that particular feature  was dense, not sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked at your notebook image.  It is a small png that requires zoom to read.  We strongly encourage, some even demand, that you copy-n-paste code and errors. We need to see the problem, right up front, not hidden.  Otherwise we are likely to move to the next question.

`broadcast` errors usually occur when doing some sort of math on two arrays, or when (my second guess) assigning one array to a slice of another.  But this case is a more obscure one, trying to make an object dtype array from (n,4) and (n,300) shaped arrays.

You are doing `hstack((ns, array2))`.  With an ordinary `np.hstack` that would work and produce a (n, 304) shaped array.  But you are using `scipy.sparse.hstack`.  I don't know if that was intentional or a mistake.  You haven't hinted that you are working the `sparse` matrices.

`ns` probably was constructed from a sparse matrix, since you use `toarray()`.  But it is now a dense (numpy) array.

`sparse.hstack` is intended for sparse matrices, returning a sparse matrix.  I don't know the exact limits on using dense array inputs.  I believe it can convert dense to `coo` sparse and then do its join, but here the error occurred before it got to that step.

---

This reproduces your error:

```
In [37]: from scipy import sparse
```

Trying to use sparse hstack on two dense arrays:

```
In [38]: sparse.hstack([np.ones((3,4)),np.zeros((3,2))])                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-a9d8036b5a44> in <module>
----> 1 sparse.hstack([np.ones((3,4)),np.zeros((3,2))])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    463 
    464     """
--> 465     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    466 
    467 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    543     """
    544 
--> 545     blocks = np.asarray(blocks, dtype='object')
    546 
    547     if blocks.ndim != 2:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,4) into shape (3)
```

But if we first convert one (even the 2nd) to sparse:

```
In [39]: sparse.hstack([np.ones((3,4)),sparse.coo_matrix(np.zeros((3,2)))])     
Out[39]: 
<3x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 12 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [40]: _.A                                                                    
Out[40]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

of course the right way to join two dense arrays:

```
In [41]: np.hstack([np.ones((3,4)),np.zeros((3,2))])                            
Out[41]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

The `array(...,object)` error is a bit obscure; it arises because both arrays are dense and have the same first dimension.  It's a known issue in `numpy`.  Since `sparse.hstack` was intended for use on sparse matrices, its developers can be excused for ignoring this `numpy` misuse.

===

`sparse.vstack` does work with dense arrays, with shapes like (3,4) and (5,4), because `np.array(..., object)` does make a valid object dtype array.  But if the shapes match, e.g. (3,4) and (3,4), neither `hstack` nor `vstack` work, but the error message is different from yours.

```
In [66]: sparse.hstack((np.ones((3,2)),np.zeros((3,2))))                        
...
ValueError: blocks must be 2-D
```

So we need to the take the docs seriously.

Comment: I actually have some features in dense format, and Since you have already seen the image, in the last cell, it seems to work, there the sparse,hstack works even with one of inputs in dense form.The problem was both the features were in dense form.Thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: `sparse.hstack` docs says: **Stack sparse matrices horizontally (column wise)**.  If it works when one of them is dense, that's a coincidence, not a design feature.  It and `vstack` should have some check to detect dense arrays.

Comment: `sparse.hstack` and `vstack` pass the task to `sparse.bmat`.  That in turn converts all input matrices to `coo` format, and combines their attributes to make a new `coo` format matrix.  So even when it works, there's no advantage to passing a dense array.  It has to be converted to sparse anyways.